# Fetching cell values based on selection in drop down list in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have a sheet called 'Student Contact Detail' as Sheet1 and another sheet called 'Student Credential' as Sheet2.

> ->Sheet1 has columns (*Sr. No.>(A), C**ontact No.(B), Department Name(C), Student ID(D)***).
>
> ->Sheet2 has columns (*Sr. No.>(A), **Contact No.(B), Department Name(C), Student ID(D)**, Login Link(E), User Name (F)*).

I can fetch data of ***Row (C)& (D) by (A)*** with formulae `"=vlookup($B2,'Student Contact Detail'!$B:$D,2,false)`" & "`=vlookup($B2,'Student Contact Detail'!$B:$D,3,false)`".

But I also want a functionality, where I can fetch ***Contact No.(B)*** using ***Department Name(C)***.

Tried Formula `=vlookup($C3,'Student Contact Detail'!$B:$D,1,false)` but is showing ***#NA*** error.
ANY SOLUTION PLEASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vishalsagar, I assume that there only one Contact No for each Departent Name?  If so, try this:

```
=VLOOKUP($C2,{'Student Contact Detail'!C:C,'Student Contact Detail'!B:B},2,0)
```

Since `VLOOKUP` can only look to the right, we cheat, and build a virtual array, using {...}.  We put column C first, and then beside it, we put column B, like this: {C:C,B:B}.

Then we use `VLOOKUP` to lookup column C, and find value B.

Other ways such as `INDEX(MATCH` can also be used, but I like this trick of just reversing the columns with a virtual array, for its simplicity.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, just a minor change got it working, which was `=VLOOKUP($C2,{'Student Contact Detail'!C:C,'Student Contact Detail'!B:B},2,0)` I used **2** instead of **1**, as the column to fetch is 2nd. Thanks Alot @kirkg13

Comment: The array was new to me, but I'm glad to learn this.

Comment: Right, my mistake, after I reversed the columns.  Since I wasn't using a sample sheet to test it out, always a chance of a mistake happening.  I'll correct my answer, and be more careful next time.  Glad it helped!